# Fix Pardot to Salesforce Sync. We get "A country/territory must be specified before specifying a state value for field: State/Province"

Tags: trigger, leads, pardot, sync

When we sync a new Prospect to a Salesforce Lead, we get

```
Field Integrity Exception: 
A country/territory must be specified before specifying a state value for field: State/Province
```

Now when we inspect the Prospect, we indeed see that the State contains an invalid value "Not applicable".

So I created a "Before Insert" Trigger in Salesforce that sets the State field to Null if it is invalid. The Trigger works, and if we sync the Prospect to Salesforce I see in the debugging that the State and StateCode fields are Nullified in the Before Trigger.

All in all, the Salesforce logging shows *no* error. After we nullify the State field, the Lead looks fine.

However, we *still* get the same error message in Pardot, and consequently the Lead is *not* inserted into Salesforce. Any clue? What can I investigate?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found it. It's a Salesforce bug :-(

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4OMAA0

As the bug title states: "State and Country picklist validation is still enforced even when a before trigger changes to a correct value". That is exactly what I am encountering here.

Let's remain positive, but that might take a few years to solve.